# iOS - UILabel attributedText in IB not able to change font size

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, nsattributedstring

In interfaceBuilder i have created a simple UILabel. It has text inside and i set it to attributedText.  I'm not able to change the font size.  Each time i try to change the font and run the program the font remains unchanged.  In fact what i have tried is after i alter the font size and run the app and return to IB the font has been reset on its own !!

here are my IB settings for UILabel attributedText:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourlabel.font = [yourlabel.font fontWithSize:16];
```

or

```
[yourlabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
```

Setting the font size is better done in your code, typically in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` methods.

This link --> [HERE](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/changing-font-size-of-an-nsattributedstring/) <-- has another way by creating a method to handle changing font size in attributed text. Not bad either.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text you want to modify

For example ： Selected the "platinum" then reset font